# Oauth 2.0 Authentication using google-api-services-oauth2

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I ran the code from below url. This is used for oauth2.o authentication
[OAuth2Sample.java](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/oauth2/cmdline/OAuth2Sample.java)

I am trying to authenticate, but instead of google as auth server, i want to use okta or any corporate auth server.

How can i change the redirect url or token endpoints.

By default it uses google endpoints  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

I want to override it to use my custom auth server endpoints.

Could appreciate if you can helpe me here.

Answer (score 0):

The sample in question [OAuth2Sample.java](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/oauth2/cmdline/OAuth2Sample.java) uses the [Google api Java client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client) which is designed to allow developer to access Google discovery apis.

Google Discovery apis allow access to different Google systems, drive, calendar, YouTube to name a few.  The only way to get access to those systems is to go though googles authentication server which is located at  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth  You cant access google systems using okta or any corporate auth server as they dont have access to googles systems.